# git-svn fetch error "0 [main] ?4828 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /libexec/git-core/git-svn - Win3 2 error 6, handle io_handle<0x0>"

Tags: perl, git-svn

When I ran `git svn fetch`, I got the following error message. How do I fix it? Thanks very much.

```
F:\gitsvntest>git svn fetch
      0 [main] ?4828 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /libexec/git-core/git-svn - Win3
2 error 6, handle io_handle
    272 [main] ?4828 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/Term/Cap.pm
 - Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
   4902 [main] ?4828 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /dev/pipew - Win32 error 6, hand
le io_handle
   5005 [main] ?4828 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /f/gitsvntest/.git/bk7BX7R03b -
Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
   5079 [main] ?4828 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /f/gitsvntest/.git/aA7kR4Avx4 -
Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
      0 [main] perl.exe" 3860 fork_copy: loaded dll data/bss pass 0 failed, 0x67
604000..0x67604014, done 0, windows pid 4828, Win32 error 487
      0 [main] ?1672 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /libexec/git-core/git-svn - Win3
2 error 6, handle io_handle
    256 [main] ?1672 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/Term/Cap.pm
 - Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
   4911 [main] ?1672 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /dev/pipew - Win32 error 6, hand
le io_handle
   5015 [main] ?1672 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /f/gitsvntest/.git/bk7BX7R03b -
Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
   5078 [main] ?1672 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /f/gitsvntest/.git/aA7kR4Avx4 -
Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
5028759 [main] perl.exe" 3860 fork_copy: loaded dll data/bss pass 0 failed, 0x67
604000..0x67604014, done 0, windows pid 1672, Win32 error 487
      0 [main] ?4636 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /libexec/git-core/git-svn - Win3
2 error 6, handle io_handle
    200 [main] ?4636 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/Term/Cap.pm
 - Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
   4700 [main] ?4636 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /dev/pipew - Win32 error 6, hand
le io_handle
   4761 [main] ?4636 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /f/gitsvntest/.git/bk7BX7R03b -
Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
   4816 [main] ?4636 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /f/gitsvntest/.git/aA7kR4Avx4 -
Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
10058702 [main] perl.exe" 3860 fork_copy: loaded dll data/bss pass 0 failed, 0x6
7604000..0x67604014, done 0, windows pid 4636, Win32 error 487
      0 [main] ?2372 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /libexec/git-core/git-svn - Win3
2 error 6, handle io_handle
    207 [main] ?2372 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/Term/Cap.pm
 - Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
   4974 [main] ?2372 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /dev/pipew - Win32 error 6, hand
le io_handle
   5036 [main] ?2372 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /f/gitsvntest/.git/bk7BX7R03b -
Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
   5092 [main] ?2372 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /f/gitsvntest/.git/aA7kR4Avx4 -
Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
15090148 [main] perl.exe" 3860 fork_copy: loaded dll data/bss pass 0 failed, 0x6
7604000..0x67604014, done 0, windows pid 2372, Win32 error 487
      0 [main] ?3928 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /libexec/git-core/git-svn - Win3
2 error 6, handle io_handle
-   4876 [main] ?3928 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/Term/Cap.p
m - Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
   1204 [main] ?3928 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /dev/pipew - Win32 error 6, hand
le io_handle
   1506 [main] ?3928 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /f/gitsvntest/.git/bk7BX7R03b -
Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
   1608 [main] ?3928 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /f/gitsvntest/.git/aA7kR4Avx4 -
Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
20135923 [main] perl.exe" 3860 fork_copy: loaded dll data/bss pass 0 failed, 0x6
7604000..0x67604014, done 0, windows pid 3928, Win32 error 487
      0 [main] ?2188 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /libexec/git-core/git-svn - Win3
2 error 6, handle io_handle
    205 [main] ?2188 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/Term/Cap.pm
 - Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
   4821 [main] ?2188 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /dev/pipew - Win32 error 6, hand
le io_handle
   4882 [main] ?2188 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /f/gitsvntest/.git/bk7BX7R03b -
Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
   4938 [main] ?2188 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /f/gitsvntest/.git/aA7kR4Avx4 -
Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
25169941 [main] perl.exe" 3860 fork_copy: loaded dll data/bss pass 0 failed, 0x6
7604000..0x67604014, done 0, windows pid 2188, Win32 error 487
      0 [main] ?3924 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /libexec/git-core/git-svn - Win3
2 error 6, handle io_handle
    207 [main] ?3924 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/Term/Cap.pm
 - Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
   5118 [main] ?3924 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /dev/pipew - Win32 error 6, hand
le io_handle
   5698 [main] ?3924 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /f/gitsvntest/.git/bk7BX7R03b -
Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
   5821 [main] ?3924 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /f/gitsvntest/.git/aA7kR4Avx4 -
Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
30219728 [main] perl.exe" 3860 fork_copy: loaded dll data/bss pass 0 failed, 0x6
7604000..0x67604014, done 0, windows pid 3924, Win32 error 487
      0 [main] ?4480 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /libexec/git-core/git-svn - Win3
2 error 6, handle io_handle
    273 [main] ?4480 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/Term/Cap.pm
 - Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
   6263 [main] ?4480 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /dev/pipew - Win32 error 6, hand
le io_handle
   6597 [main] ?4480 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /f/gitsvntest/.git/bk7BX7R03b -
Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
   6682 [main] ?4480 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /f/gitsvntest/.git/aA7kR4Avx4 -
Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
35259447 [main] perl.exe" 3860 fork_copy: loaded dll data/bss pass 0 failed, 0x6
7604000..0x67604014, done 0, windows pid 4480, Win32 error 487
      0 [main] ?1500 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /libexec/git-core/git-svn - Win3
2 error 6, handle io_handle
    208 [main] ?1500 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/Term/Cap.pm
 - Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
   5733 [main] ?1500 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /dev/pipew - Win32 error 6, hand
le io_handle
   5811 [main] ?1500 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /f/gitsvntest/.git/bk7BX7R03b -
Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
   5876 [main] ?1500 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /f/gitsvntest/.git/aA7kR4Avx4 -
Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
40306890 [main] perl.exe" 3860 fork_copy: loaded dll data/bss pass 0 failed, 0x6
7604000..0x67604014, done 0, windows pid 1500, Win32 error 487
      0 [main] ?3356 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /libexec/git-core/git-svn - Win3
2 error 6, handle io_handle
    260 [main] ?3356 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/Term/Cap.pm
 - Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
   1361 [main] ?3356 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /dev/pipew - Win32 error 6, hand
le io_handle
   6935 [main] ?3356 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /f/gitsvntest/.git/bk7BX7R03b -
Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
   7092 [main] ?3356 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /f/gitsvntest/.git/aA7kR4Avx4 -
Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
45360601 [main] perl.exe" 3860 fork_copy: loaded dll data/bss pass 0 failed, 0x6
7604000..0x67604014, done 0, windows pid 3356, Win32 error 487
      0 [main] ?1284 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /libexec/git-core/git-svn - Win3
2 error 6, handle io_handle
    698 [main] ?1284 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/Term/Cap.pm
 - Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
   6959 [main] ?1284 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /dev/pipew - Win32 error 6, hand
le io_handle
   7059 [main] ?1284 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /f/gitsvntest/.git/bk7BX7R03b -
Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
   2267 [main] ?1284 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /f/gitsvntest/.git/aA7kR4Avx4 -
Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
50404771 [main] perl.exe" 3860 fork_copy: loaded dll data/bss pass 0 failed, 0x6
7604000..0x67604014, done 0, windows pid 1284, Win32 error 487
      0 [main] ?4120 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /libexec/git-core/git-svn - Win3
2 error 6, handle io_handle
    317 [main] ?4120 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/Term/Cap.pm
 - Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
   6634 [main] ?4120 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /dev/pipew - Win32 error 6, hand
le io_handle
   6699 [main] ?4120 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /f/gitsvntest/.git/bk7BX7R03b -
Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
   6755 [main] ?4120 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /f/gitsvntest/.git/aA7kR4Avx4 -
Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
55449698 [main] perl.exe" 3860 fork_copy: loaded dll data/bss pass 0 failed, 0x6
7604000..0x67604014, done 0, windows pid 4120, Win32 error 487
      0 [main] ?3440 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /libexec/git-core/git-svn - Win3
2 error 6, handle io_handle
    207 [main] ?3440 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/Term/Cap.pm
 - Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
    852 [main] ?3440 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /dev/pipew - Win32 error 6, hand
le io_handle
   6945 [main] ?3440 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /f/gitsvntest/.git/bk7BX7R03b -
Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
   7040 [main] ?3440 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /f/gitsvntest/.git/aA7kR4Avx4 -
Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
61057400 [main] perl.exe" 3860 fork_copy: loaded dll data/bss pass 0 failed, 0x6
7604000..0x67604014, done 0, windows pid 3440, Win32 error 487
      0 [main] ?5460 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /libexec/git-core/git-svn - Win3
2 error 6, handle io_handle
    474 [main] ?5460 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/Term/Cap.pm
 - Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
   5882 [main] ?5460 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /dev/pipew - Win32 error 6, hand
le io_handle
   7563 [main] ?5460 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /f/gitsvntest/.git/bk7BX7R03b -
Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
  12664 [main] ?5460 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /f/gitsvntest/.git/aA7kR4Avx4 -
Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
66108342 [main] perl.exe" 3860 fork_copy: loaded dll data/bss pass 0 failed, 0x6
7604000..0x67604014, done 0, windows pid 5460, Win32 error 487
      0 [main] ?3084 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /libexec/git-core/git-svn - Win3
2 error 6, handle io_handle
    304 [main] ?3084 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/Term/Cap.pm
 - Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
    699 [main] ?3084 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /dev/pipew - Win32 error 6, hand
le io_handle
    843 [main] ?3084 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /f/gitsvntest/.git/bk7BX7R03b -
Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
    929 [main] ?3084 fhandler_base::fork_fixup: /f/gitsvntest/.git/aA7kR4Avx4 -
Win32 error 6, handle io_handle
71155467 [main] perl.exe" 3860 fork_copy: loaded dll data/bss pass 0 failed, 0x6
7604000..0x67604014, done 0, windows pid 3084, Win32 error 487
```

Answer (score 1):

Every now and then one hits this problem with Cygwin. The fix is [running `rebaseall`](http://cygwin.wikia.com/wiki/Rebaseall).

> Sometimes, after updating or installing packages, you'll start to get strange errors related to `fork()` or .dll loading. These errors are usually solved by rebasing your packages.
>
> ### Rebasing
>
> #### Installing Required Packages
>
> To rebase, you first need to install two packages:
>
> - dash (or ash)
> - rebase
>
> #### Stop Running Services
>
> Now that you have the packages you need, you'll need to make sure no Cygwin-based services are running (including X11, SSH, etc). If you don’t feel up to figuring out how to stop every running Cygwin service, restarting your computer in safe-mode might be an effective hack.
>
> #### Rebase Everything
>
> Now that no Cygwin services are running, you can rebase your packages. Open a Windows command prompt (by going to the "Run" menu and entering "cmd"). Once there, type or right-click and paste the following commands. Be patient, this’ll take a minute:
>
> ```
> \cygwin\bin\dash -c '/usr/bin/rebaseall'
> exit
> exit
> ```
>
> As an alternative method you may also try under Windows 7 going to `C:\cygwin\bin`, and via right-click running `dash.exe` as Administrator, and then at the dash command prompt, type the following commands:
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/rebaseall -v
> exit
> ```
>
> Rebasing all your packages will take a few minutes but should resolve the forking errors. Unfortunately, this seems to be machine-specific and can't be done by Cygwin's upstream.

For more, read [Rebaseall on the Cygwin wiki](http://cygwin.wikia.com/wiki/Rebaseall).